# How to customize Django's CSRF handling on a per view basis

Tags: django, django-csrf

In a Django application I have `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` enabled. This means that a `POST` request without a CSRF token will be rejected and result in a HTTP response Forbidden (status code 403).

Now I have one view that needs to handle a missing CSRF token in a different way. Instead of a 403 response I want to redirect the user to a different page.

I came up with the following solution (based on the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#scenarios):

```
@csrf_exempt  # Disable CSRF middleware
@requires_csrf_token  # Apply customized CSRF middleware
def my_view(request):
    if getattr(request, 'csrf_processing_done', False):
        # CSRF success, process request
        ...
    else:
        # CSRF failed, redirect
        return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
```

Which is nice and short and seems to work perfectly fine. My issue however is that it relies on an implementation detail.

The current version of Django only ever sets `csrf_processing_done` to `True` in the `_accept` method of `CsrfViewMiddleware` (https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.4/django/middleware/csrf.py#L141)

The `requires_csrf_token` is based on a customized version of `CsrfViewMiddleware` that overrides `_reject` to do nothing (https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.4/django/views/decorators/csrf.py#L17) (it keeps `_accept` the same).

So my current implementation will work as long as Django doesn't change the implementation of this middleware and decorator.

Since `csrf_processing_done` is not part of the public API (I asked:  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31360), I'm left with the question; is there a way to customize the handling of CSRF failure in a way that doesn't rely on this implementation detail?